# Copy data from several Word documents to one Excel workbook using Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have about 100 Word documents and from each I want to copy data and paste it all in one Excel workbook.

I came up with this code which opens one Word document, copies data, pastes it to Excel and closes the Word document:

```
Sub WordDataToExcel()
Dim myObj
 Dim myWB
 Dim mySh
 Dim txt As String, Lgth As Long, Strt As Long
 Dim i As Long
 Dim oRng As Range
 Dim Tgt As String
 Dim TgtFile As String
 Dim arr()
 Dim ArrSize As Long
 Dim ArrIncrement As Long
 ArrIncrement = 1000
 ArrSize = ArrIncrement
 ReDim arr(ArrSize)
Dim wrdDoc As Object

Documents.Open ("D:\ekr5_i.doc")

TgtFile = "result.xlsx"

Tgt = "D:\" & TgtFile

'finds the text string of Lgth lenght
 txt = "thetext"
 Lgth = 85
 Strt = Len(txt)

 'Return data to array
 With Selection
 .HomeKey unit:=wdStory
 With .Find
 .ClearFormatting
 .Forward = True
 .Text = txt
 .Execute
 While .Found
 i = i + 1
 Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range _
 (Start:=Selection.Range.Start + Strt, _
 End:=Selection.Range.End + Lgth)
 arr(i) = oRng.Text
 oRng.Start = oRng.End
 .Execute
 If i = ArrSize - 20 Then
 ArrSize = ArrSize + ArrIncrement
 ReDim Preserve arr(ArrSize)
 End If
 Wend
 End With
 End With
 ReDim Preserve arr(i)

 'Set target and write data
 Set myObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set myWB = myObj.Workbooks.Open(Tgt)
 Set mySh = myWB.Sheets(1)
 With mySh
 .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(i, 1)) = myObj.Transpose(arr)
 End With

 'Tidy up
 myWB.Close True
 myObj.Quit
 ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
 Set mySh = Nothing
 Set myWB = Nothing
 Set myObj = Nothing
 End Sub
```

I need to loop through all the documents in the folder.

I have implemented the same with Excel workbooks, but I don't know how for Word documents.

Here is the code for Excel workbooks:

```
Sub combine_into_one()
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strPath$, Pivot$, sUserName$, sFolderName$, sSourceName$, x&
Dim oFldialog As FileDialog
Dim oFolder

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set oFldialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With oFldialog
If .Show = -1 Then
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    sFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
End If
End With

Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sFolderName)

Workbooks.Add: Pivot = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Destination workbook

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
Workbooks(Pivot).Activate

x = Workbooks(Pivot).Sheets(1).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

Workbooks.Open Filename:=oFile: sSourceName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Workbooks(sSourceName).Activate
    Workbooks(sSourceName).Sheets(1).[A80:Q94].copy

Workbooks(Pivot).Activate
Workbooks(Pivot).Sheets(1).Cells(x + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Workbooks(sSourceName).Close False
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Search for VBA code samples that use `Dir` - there are a lot around...

Comment: You have the answer in your excel code.  It is the code related to the 'For Each oFile In oFolder.Files'.  Then inside the for loop you would use code like 'set my_doc =documents.open(ofile)'.    If you are unclear about any items in VBA code you can put the cursor on the keyword and press F1 (only in the VBA IDE).  This brings up the MS help page for that keyword.  Additionally, your code would benefit from using a collection rather than an array as collections don't need to be resized, and you can use a 'for each loop' to iterate over the collection.

Answer (score 0):

There are so, so, so many things you can do between Excel & Word. The script below may help you; it has definitely served me well over time.

```
Sub OpenAndReadWordDoc()

Rows("2:1000000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select
    
    ' assumes that the previous procedure has been executed
    Dim oWordApp As Word.Application
    Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim blnStart As Boolean
    Dim r As Long
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim strFilePattern As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Long
    Dim n As Long

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        ' We started Word for this macro
        blnStart = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    r = 1 ' startrow for the copied text from the Word document
    ' Last column
    n = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

    sFolder = "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\Microsoft Excel\PWC\Resumes\"
    
    '~~> This is the extension you want to go in for
    strFilePattern = "*.doc*"
    '~~> Loop through the folder to get the word files
    strFileName = Dir(sFolder & strFilePattern)
    Do Until strFileName = ""
        sFileName = sFolder & strFileName

        '~~> Open the word doc
        Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(sFileName)
        ' Increase row number
        r = r + 1
        ' Enter file name in column A
        ws.Cells(r, 1).Value = sFileName
        
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r), Address:=sFileName, _
        SubAddress:="A" & r, TextToDisplay:=sFileName

        ' Loop through the columns
        For c = 2 To n
            If oWordDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:=Trim(ws.Cells(1, c).Value), _
                    MatchWholeWord:=True, MatchCase:=False) Then
                ' If text found, enter Yes in column number c
                ws.Cells(r, c).Value = "Yes"
            End If
        Next c
        oWordDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False

        '~~> Find next file
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

ExitHandler:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' close the Word application
    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
    If blnStart Then
        ' We started Word, so we close it
        oWordApp.Quit
    End If
    Set oWordApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

Function GetDirectory(path)
   GetDirectory = Left(path, InStrRev(path, "\"))
End Function
```

[image]

In this scenario, whatever you put in the headers of B1:K1 (or more to the right) is searched for, each word document in a folder is opened, scanned, and if the string in  B1:K1 is found, an 'x' is placed in the same x-y coordinate.